# How to define a new field in a pre-existing document in MongoDB that isn't in the schema? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am making a discord bot using MongoDB and I want to add some user-specific fields to an already existing document in MongoDB that aren't in the schema. There is a lot of data I am planning to add and I wanted it to be added automatically depending on what the user does for efficiency.

I tried to use findOneAndUpdate to set the new field and its value. I had the settings "strict" set to false and "upsert" set to true. I saved it afterwards. I did see that it was added in the Compass Community App, but when I tried to call the field later, it was undefined and I'm assuming because it isn't in the schema. I wanted to know if there was a way around this or if I made any errors.

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate({
  userID: message.author.id
}, {
  $set: {
    "xp": xpToBeAdded,
    "level": 0
   }
}, {
  strict: false,
  upsert: true
}, async (err, userAdd) => {
  await userAdd.save().catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Original users schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: String,
    serverID: Array,
    userTag: String,
    username: String,
    dbCreatedAt: Number,
    dbCreatedAtDate: String
}, {strict: false})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Comment: Mongo won't care about schema (unless you're using an ORM like Mongoose). Are you transforming your return in any way? If you see what you expect in compass, it should pull out just fine. Have to tried printing the raw response (not sure if you're transforming the return in any way as you haven't provided that code.

Comment: @mwilson I logged "user.xp" to the console directly after I saved it and it returned undefined.

Comment: what does `console.log(user)` yield? I'd also be interested in seeing the code in your `User` class

Comment: When I log user, it shows the previously defined document that follows the schema without the new field.

Comment: I bet you're not mapping that property in your User class. There's not enough code shown in your question to pin-point the issue

Comment: I edited the code to add it.

Comment: Yup. add `xp` and `level` to your mongoose model

Comment: I was trying to see if there was a way to add fields to the document without adding it to the schema.

Comment: There is, but if you want those fields returned when you query your document, you have to tell your schema about them. Otherwise, when it maps the result to your model, they will get dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing the right values in compass, but it's not being returned, it's probably because your model doesn't know about those properties. Try updating your model to this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: String,
    xp: Number,
    level: Number,
    serverID: Array,
    userTag: String,
    username: String,
    dbCreatedAt: Number,
    dbCreatedAtDate: String
}, {strict: false})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Example of what is happening (notice how `sex` doesn't get logged, even though you're passing it in as a value):

```js
class User {
 constructor(user) {
   this.name = user.name;
    this.age = user.age;
  }
}

const user1 = new User({name: 'Frank', age: 22, sex: 'M'});
console.log(user1);
```